# Adding path for python package

Tags: python, path, pythonpath

I have installed an python package namely `tavern` using `pip install tavern`, after installation it didn't added the package into the path, I manually did it after adding it to the path when I type `tavern` in the `shell` I end with this `err` `zsh: permission denied: /Users/divyanshurawat/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tavern`.

So, I tried setting up the path with the help of following commands:

1 - `open .bash_profile`

2 - `alias tavern="/Users/divyanshurawat/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tavern"`

3 - `source ~/.bash_profile`

but it still doesn't seem to work even if you write `sudo tavern`, I don't know what is missing here, maybe my approach to set the path is wrong.

This is how tavern directory looks like.

```
__init__.py,
_plugins,
core.pyc,
entry.pyc,
plugins.pyc,
response,
testutils,
__init__.pyc,
core.py,
entry.py,
plugins.py,
request,
schemas,
util
```

Answer (score 0):

/Users/divyanshurawat/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tavern is a directory, not an executable

Comment: cool @andrei I changed it to /Users/divyanshurawat/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tavern/entry.py but err is still the same.

Comment: To run tavern without pytest, you can use 'tavern-ci file_name.yaml' . You can find the documentation [here](https://tavern.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)

Comment: If I am not able to access tavern itself, how can I access tavern-ci?

Comment: The entry points for the tavern module should be in the 'bin' folder. There you should also have 'tavern-ci'

Comment: I have updated the answer with tavern dir. contents @andrei

Comment: Those are the contents of the tavern directory. The entry points shoud be in  '/opt/freeware/bin' or '/usr/bin'. I installed the tavern module on a virtual environment, so in my case the entry points are located in '/projectvenv/bin'.
Try the following code and check if that's the path for the bin directory:  
`import os  
import distutils.sysconfig    
pre = distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var("prefix")    
bindir = os.path.join(pre, "bin")  
print bindir`

Comment: these are the contents of the bin dir.
2to3   2to32.7   idle2.7   pydoc2.7  python2   python2.7-config pythonw2.7  smtpd2.py
2to3-2   idle   pydoc   python   python2-config  pythonw   smtpd.py
2to3-2.7  idle2   pydoc2   python-config  python2.7  pythonw2  smtpd2.7.py

Comment: Search for the entry point on your system.  `find / -name tavern-ci 2>/dev/null` .This is pretty much my last idea :)

Comment: thanks I found the path and added it as an alias in .bash_profile.